# Create new Gradle project in Eclipse creates only an empty folder

Tags: eclipse, gradle

When I try to [create a new Gradle project in Eclipse](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseGradle/article.html#how-to-create-a-gradle-project-for-java-with-eclipse), I get no error but no project is created. I only see this empty folder in eclipse workspace folder:

[image]

Steps I follow:

[image]
[image]

Here are my versions:

[image: Eclipse version]
[image: Gradle eclipse plugin version]

Ok my versions are old but still should be able to create a sample project. I'm behind a firewall and have updated my gradle.properties:

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=myproxy
systemProp.http.proxyPort=8080
systemProp.https.proxyHost=myproxy
systemProp.https.proxyPort=8080
```

But I think the settings in gradle.properties are not being used. I was getting socket timeout error until I changed Eclipse proxy setting from Native to Manual and entered proxy settings manually. Now I see SSL handshake exception:

```
org.gradle.tooling.GradleConnectionException: Could not install Gradle distribution from 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.8-bin.zip'.
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DistributionFactory$ZippedDistribution.getToolingImplementationClasspath(DistributionFactory.java:139)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.loader.CachingToolingImplementationLoader.create(CachingToolingImplementationLoader.java:41)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.loader.SynchronizedToolingImplementationLoader.create(SynchronizedToolingImplementationLoader.java:44)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.LazyConsumerActionExecutor.onStartAction(LazyConsumerActionExecutor.java:161)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.LazyConsumerActionExecutor.run(LazyConsumerActionExecutor.java:143)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.CancellableConsumerActionExecutor.run(CancellableConsumerActionExecutor.java:45)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.ProgressLoggingConsumerActionExecutor.run(ProgressLoggingConsumerActionExecutor.java:61)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.RethrowingErrorsConsumerActionExecutor.run(RethrowingErrorsConsumerActionExecutor.java:38)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor$1$1.run(DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.java:67)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.BlockingResultHandler.getResult(BlockingResultHandler.java:46)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultModelBuilder.get(DefaultModelBuilder.java:51)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultProjectConnection.getModel(DefaultProjectConnection.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.internal.workspace.ConnectionAwareLauncherProxy.newBuildLauncher(ConnectionAwareLauncherProxy.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.internal.DefaultGradleBuild.newBuildLauncher(DefaultGradleBuild.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.internal.workspace.InitializeNewProjectOperation.initProjectIfNotExists(InitializeNewProjectOperation.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.internal.workspace.InitializeNewProjectOperation.runInToolingApi(InitializeNewProjectOperation.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.internal.operation.ToolingApiOperations$1.runInToolingApi(ToolingApiOperations.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.internal.operation.DefaultToolingApiOperationManager$WorkspaceRunnableAdapter.run(DefaultToolingApiOperationManager.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2313)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2338)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.internal.operation.DefaultToolingApiOperationManager.run(DefaultToolingApiOperationManager.java:39)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.internal.operation.DefaultToolingApiOperationManager.run(DefaultToolingApiOperationManager.java:33)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.ui.internal.wizard.project.ProjectPreviewWizardPage$4.run(ProjectPreviewWizardPage.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:122)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:370)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:313)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:308)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:654)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.onCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:473)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.consume(CertificateMessage.java:369)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:396)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:480)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:458)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:200)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:172)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1500)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1415)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:450)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:421)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:580)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:183)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1665)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1589)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:224)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.downloadInternal(Download.java:87)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.download(Download.java:67)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DistributionInstaller$1.run(DistributionInstaller.java:128)
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:439)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:306)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:264)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:231)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:132)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:638)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
    at java.base/java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:297)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:434)
    ... 24 more
```

I tried to set Java Home in Gradle settings but it keeps showing me this annoying exclamation mark:
[image: Gradle Java Home exclamation]

How can I get rid of this exclamation mark? I think I need to find the Java installation Gradle is using. Then I'll add the certificate of https://services.gradle.org to the appropriate keystore.

Comment: The .log file in the workspace .metadata directory is the main log.

Comment: Eclipse 2021-12 is 5 releases behind. Please upgrade. Please tell which with Java version do you run Eclipse and which Gradle version did you choose (on the next _New Gradle Project_ wizard page). Be aware that not all Gradle and Java versions work together (has a `lib` folder been created in the `eclipse-workspace v2021` directory?). By the way, better avoid spaces in file and folder names.

Comment: _"Ok my versions are old but still should be able to create a sample project."_ - Sure, it's possible, but more difficult and you obviously failed for unknown reasons. Always make sure the software you are using is up to date before asking something on Stack Overflow, otherwise ask on [Retrocomputing Stack Exchange](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/). You have to configure your proxy also in Eclipse in the preferences _General > Network Connections_, (it's unclear why you think _Native_ is enough here, but for Gradle you set it manually).

Comment: Seems like your system has networking problems (SocketTimeoutException) or the remote servers were unavailable for a short taime.

Comment: The problem was with Eclipse proxy settings. I've changed it from Native to Manual and now I'm getting handshake error. Now I need to find the java gradle is using to add the certificate to its keystore.

Comment: With an up-to-date Java, you probably wouldn't need to add a certificate. Please notice my comments above.

Comment: I wish it was up to me to upgrade, but I'm working in a big bank with around 1000 developers. Our infrastructure team needs to be convinced but I'm sure they want to upgrade too. There must be thousands of lines of code affected by the upgrade, so they must be waiting for a better (!) motivation.

Comment: To sum it up: downloading of something to run it on your local machine fails because the software used to download is outdated and you refuse to download and run up-to-date software on your local machine. A bank should take security more seriously instead of doing the opposite. Why are lines of code affected by an upgrade? `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171` means Java 8 update 171 (instead of 372), containing revoked certificates, but missing current certificates and other security updates. What is your motivation to spend your time on retrocomputing instead of being productive? ;)